# Infer base type for two arguments in Typescript

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference

While implementing a generic function on sets in Typescript, I noticed that the compiler is unable to infer the base type of two arguments.

```js
function union<T>(first: Set<T>, second: Set<T>): Set<T> {
  const newSet = new Set<T>(first);
  for (const element of second)
    newSet.add(element);
  return newSet;
}

class Animal { }
class Dog extends Animal {
  bark() { console.info('Woof!'); }
}
class Cat extends Animal {
  meow() { console.info('Meow!'); }
}

const a = new Set<Dog>();
const b = new Set<Cat>();
```

Then if I call union, Typescript is unable to infer that `T` should be `Animal`.

```js
const c = union(a, b);
// This results in the error:
// Argument of type 'Set<Cat>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Set<Dog>'.
// Property 'bark' is missing in type 'Cat' but required in type 'Dog'.ts(2345)
```

But if I explicitly call union with `T = Animal`, it works fine:

```js
const d = union<Animal>(a, b);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try yo use union of types:

```js
function union<T extends Animal, U extends Animal>(first: Set<T>, second: Set<U>) {
    const newSet = new Set<T | U>(first);
    for (const element of second)
        newSet.add(element);
    return newSet;
}

class Animal { }

class Dog extends Animal {
    bark() { console.info('Woof!'); }
}
class Cat extends Animal {
    meow() { console.info('Meow!'); }
}

const a = new Set<Dog>();
const b = new Set<Cat>();

const c = union(a, b);
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABOeYA8AVRBTAHlbMAEwGdEBBMGAWwEMAbAGkQFUd9DSKq76A%20ABTAYAJxJQAXIgDK2KJj7MS2CAiJTZ8lnwCUiAN4AoRCcSqw4xGGwB3TYgC8V2zLmZEAH1aDhYqDoBuY1NgOBFEAXNLbHpsakIoRDhgRGVzIh1g01NrOzkAOloiIgEYuITArMQRORARJFzNIIBfQ0MIeloSMkoaBgNEVvbO7sQAETgAc3YCYh6efqNsgCNaEQBrAT19MwQSOFj8mDBQgQByAHU4ZIBCM8DBw1aOrrIAYVpEvFmuXt4DKrxOA2LYDKIHbBHE5wc4AWWwwLuD1aQyiiVojmcNlc8gmk0ElTRiGWmNyOLQHygBKC7T2iQgmJQCAEtGYy0qQA)

Adding extra generic argument `U` helps TS to infer the type of both Set